# Init object error TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing

I am trying to do some image processing with the following code:

```
Image.open('C:\\temp\\img')
width, height = im.size
im  = im.resize((width*8,height*8), Image.BICUBIC)

pixdata = im.load()
for y in xrange(im.size[1]):
    for x in xrange(im.size[0]):
        if pixdata[x, y][0] < 165:
            pixdata = (0, 0, 0, 255)

for y in xrange(im.size[1]):
    for x in xrange(im.size[0]):
        if pixdata[x, y][1] < 165:
            pixdata = (0, 0, 0, 255)

for y in xrange(im.size[1]):
    for x in xrange(im.size[0]):
        if pixdata[x, y][2] > 0:
            pixdata[x, y] = (255, 255, 255, 255)
```

however when I am doing the above i get a TypeError. The pixdata is stored on memory properly but no idea why this is giving this error.

```
if pixdata[x, y][0] < 165:
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're reassigning `pixdata`. It starts out as an `Image` object, but then:

```
for y in xrange(im.size[1]):
    for x in xrange(im.size[0]):
        if pixdata[x, y][0] < 165:
            pixdata = (0, 0, 0, 255)
```

Now `pixdata` is (or could be; the `if` test may or may not pass) `(0, 0, 0, 255)`.  Now the next time you try to access `pixdata[x, y][0]` (in a later iteration of that same loop, or in another loop later) you are trying to index into `(0, 0, 0, 255)` rather than the image data, and this obviously isn't going to work.

Solution: don't throw away `pixdata` if you still need it. You want `pixdata[x, y] = (0, 0, 0, 255)` probably. You did it right in your third loop, make it the same way in your first two.